# broadcasting with google protocol buffers on c++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a numbers of computers working on the same problem and I need each computer to be able to broadcast the solution to the others.

Is this possible to get this functionality with Google Protocol Buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protocol Buffers is a mechanism for serialising data and does not have any network transport component. You could use it to prepare messages for broadcast, but won't help you to do the actual broadcast. For that, you might like to take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) or perhaps raw UDP.